# Evaluating irrational values of functions with Taylor series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Calculate the following using Taylor expansion such that the error will be smaller than $10^{-3}$.
>
> 1. $\tan 46^\circ$
> 2. $(31)^{1/5}$

1. My problem is that I don't know if I can avoid to use an irrational value like $\pi$(?)

   Since the taylor polynomial won't work with degrees, I have to convert it to radians. Other then that we just need to place $\frac {46\pi}{180}$ in the expansion for $\tan x$, at about the sixth order I got the desired error.
2. I tried several functions, none worked so far: $x^{1/5}, 31^{1/x}$ even $(2^x-1)^{1/x}$. any hints?

Note: no integrals.

Comment: For the second, expanding $x^{1/5}$ about $a=32$ should do the job.

Comment: @AndréNicolas oh I didn't think about moving from around 0,1 or 2... How did you know it's 32?

Comment: Hint: these problems are usually small perturbations about exact values.

Comment: Because our number is close to the very nice number $32^{1/5}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see. Does it matter if I get a negative value from checking the error? ((31)^(1/5)-(2-1/80-1/6400-3/1024000 )=-6.56480419e-8)

Comment: There is signed error ams unsigned error. Here unsigned error (absolute value of the error) is to be made small.

Comment: For your $f(x)$, you can expand $x^{1/5}$ in powers of $x-32$, or alternately and equivalently expand $(32+x)^{1/5}$ in powers of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $31^{1/5}$ use the function $y=\sqrt[5]{31+x}$ , then you can find the taylor series at $x=1$
the Taylor series is 
$$y=2+\frac{x-1}{80}+\frac{(x-1)^2}{6400}+\frac{3(x-1)^3}{1024000}+.....$$
to find what you need ,put $x=0$